# SQL Statement.. multiple tables with same multiple Id's

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

[image]I am working in VB.Net connection to an SQL Server 2008

**This Works -->** Dim query = "SELECT wo.WorkOrderID, wo.WorkOrderNo FROM dbo.WorkOrder wo"

**This Does not work -->** Dim query = "SELECT wo.WorkOrderID, wo.WorkOrderNo, wod.LineNo FROM dbo.WorkOrder wo, dbo.WorkOrderDetails wod"

**This does not work either -->** Dim query = "SELECT wo.WorkOrderID, wo.WorkOrderNo, wod.LineNo FROM dbo.WorkOrder wo, dbo.WorkOrderDetails wod WHERE wo.WorkOrderID = wod.WorkOrderID"

I am assuming its because in the WorkOrderDetails the WorkOrderId has multiple of the same ID

- In WorkOrder the WorkOrderID seems to be incremental.. 1,2,3 etc..
- In WorkOrderDetails the WorkOrderID is like this.. 1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3  etc..

Any ideas on how to get this to work? I can not figure it out..

- Incorrent syntax near the keyword "LineNo". Is the error I get

**I just tried this also -->** "SELECT WorkOrderID, WorkOrderNo, LineNo FROM dbo.WorkOrder JOIN dbo.WorkOrderDetails ON dbo.WorkOrder.WorkOrderID = dbo.WorkOrderDetails.WorkOrderID"

Does not seem to be working.. same error

Comment: What does "don't work" mean? Error? Wrong data? What?

Comment: Incorrent syntax near the keyword "LineNo".  Is the error I get

Comment: please use ANSI style joins....

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on SQL, but your syntax for creating Aliases seems to be unique to a specific RDBMS. Which RDBMS are you using? Also, this isn't a VB.Net question, but simply a SQL question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LineNo` is a [reserved keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238507%28v=sql.80%29.aspx). Use a [Delimited Identifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224033%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

```
SELECT WorkOrderID, WorkOrderNo, [LineNo]
FROM dbo.WorkOrder
  JOIN dbo.WorkOrderDetails
    ON dbo.WorkOrder.WorkOrderID = dbo.WorkOrderDetails.WorkOrderID
```

Answer (score 0):

Use join:

```
Dim query = 
"SELECT wo.WorkOrderID,
       wo.WorkOrderNo, 
       wod.[LineNo] FROM dbo.WorkOrder wo
                 JOIN dbo.WorkOrderDetails wod 
                 ON wo.WorkOrderID = wod.WorkOrderID"
```

This site will help you to start :

[sql tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp)

BEST REGARDS